# Jenkins fails the build saying "no space left on device" but corresponding EC2 instance does have enough space

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration

My recent Jenkins build failed with the following message:

```
12:56:53 Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
12:56:53 Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
12:56:53 Discovered Package: sentry/sentry-laravel
12:56:53 Package manifest generated successfully.
12:57:00 Error processing tar file(exit status 1): open /var/www/xela-worker/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Standards/Generic/Tests/Functions/FunctionCallArgumentSpacingUnitTest.php: no space left on device
12:57:00 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
12:57:01 [Set GitHub commit status (universal)] ERROR on repos [] (sha:95841c2) with context:Xela-Worker CI
12:57:01 [Set GitHub commit status (universal)] ERROR on repos [] (sha:95841c2) with context:Xela-Worker CI
12:57:01 Finished: FAILURE
```

[image]

I ssh'ed into the corresponding EC2 instance and I typed:

> df -T -h

It clearly says that there is enough space:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  487M     0  487M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     100M   13M   87M  13% /run
/dev/xvda1     ext4       20G   13G  6.3G  67% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     498M     0  498M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     498M     0  498M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

What would be the next step to investigate and on which end? AWS dashboard or the instance (SSH) itself?

PS. I can fully access Jenkins through the web interface via browser. No 500 errors, fast, works, all good.

Comment: Try `df -i`.  You may be out of inodes.

Answer (score 1):

check for iNode space on that server.

`Command --> df -i`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Slave/Build Server space, where your jenkins job is executed. Usually People prefer Master-Slave Jenkins Setup. Please read [Jenkins Master-Slave](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-master-and-slave-in-Jenkins) to understand more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the space after the build has run or during the run. This might be case where when the build runs it occupies space and after certain time it fails because of no space.

You should check the space when the build is running.